# Override prestashop class to make public a protected method

Tags: overriding, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to extend the AdminImportController on Prestashop to make public the copyImg function. So i made my own simple class whose code is just this

```php
class MyAdminImportController extends AdminImportControllerCore {
    public static function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = null, $url, $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true) {
        return parent::copyImg($id_entity, $id_image, $url, $entity, $regenerate);
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

```
Runtime Notice: Declaration of MyAdminImportController::copyImg() should be compatible with AdminImportControllerCore::copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = NULL, $url = '', $entity = 'products', $regenerate = true)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm stupid. The declaration must be identical. I've copied the declaration from probably another version of prestashop. The problem was the `$url=''` parts